# Custom unselected tab text color in SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, tabs, android-text-color

I am using the `SlidingTabLayout` class to display tabs in my Android application.

I'm using my custom tab view which I set with the `setCustomTabView`function. Although I can easily customize the selected tab text color, I can not find a way to customize the text color of the unselected tab. In the L preview documentation they suggest that it should be `#fff` 60%, and I want to use that exact same value also. I looked at the `SlidingTabLayout` and `SlidingTabStrip` classes, but could not figure out where should I make modifications.

Comment: How did you change the selected tab text color?

Comment: See my answer.. I defined a selector (in the colors folder) and set it as the textColor attribute of the view I am using as a tab view.. this worked for me..

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It shows only unselected color.

Comment: Maybe you should check out skywall's answer.. apparently my solution did not work for him also..

Comment: Yes, I tried skywall's answer as well. But no luck. The color of my tabs don't change. Is there a way we can change the color of the sliding strip?

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to change the color of the strip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite simple, actually.. I don't know why I did not think of it sooner..

For everybody who wonder, you should simply create `tab_text.xml` in the res/colors folder, with content:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/unselected" />
</selector>
```

And then set the defined xml (`tab_text.xml`) to the `textColor` attribute of the custom tab view (in my case the custom view is a simple `TextView`).

Answer (score 0):

Sandra's approach didn't work for me, because `setSelected()` is not called for specific view. [My solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26462476/1103478)