# Custom selected tab text color in SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, colors, tabs

I'm using the SlidingTabLayout from google (https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html).

It works well, but what I want it is to put the selected title in bold and with a different color...

Regarding this post :
[Custom unselected tab text color in SlidingTabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568392/custom-unselected-tab-text-color-in-slidingtablayout)

I make a text_tab.xml in drawable with the selector:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:color="@android:color/selected" android:state_selected="true" />
 <item android:color="@android:color/unselected" />
 </selector>
```

When in the populateTabStrip() method I put

```
 tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.text_tab));
```

The color is always the one of unselected...

I'm probably doing something wrong, or maybe there is another way to customise the selected tab title.

Someone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your question, but did you have an answer about the selected title in bold ?

Comment: In the onPageSelected() method, I just add a method called updateTab(position).
In this method I'm checking all the tab, for the tab at the position selected, I'm updating the color and change the font to be bold.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is, sliding layout do not set item's state as `selected`. Here is my approach to solve the problem.

1) Create **COLOR** selector (`ColorStateList`) for your view. You can imagine it this way:

**/res/color/tab_text_color.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

2) Place created selector to your item's view `textColor` (or other required) attribute:

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:textColor="@color/tab_text_color"
  ... />
```

3) Do this changes in file SlidingTabLayout.java:

```
View oldSelection = null; // new field indicating old selected item

// method to remove `selected` state from old one
private void removeOldSelection() { 
    if(oldSelection != null) {
        oldSelection.setSelected(false);
    }
}

// improve method scrollToTab() as follows
private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {

        if(positionOffset == 0 && selectedChild != oldSelection) { // added part
            selectedChild.setSelected(true);
            removeOldSelection();
            oldSelection = selectedChild;
        }

        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    removeOldSelection(); // add those two lines
    oldSelection = null;
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too, except I found when scrolling to the left, the left text is selected right away instead of when it is actually scrolled to.

I changed it to this:
`if (positionOffset == 0 && selectedChild != oldSelection) {`

Comment: @skywall - Could you help me changing the bacground color when clicked? Currently it shows the default holo blue.

Comment: @AtulOHolic Create custom selector (`ColorStateList`) and place it to the item's view background attribute `android:background="@color/my_color_selector"`

Comment: @skywall - I tried and the background did change. However now the selector was not shown. Any idea why?

Comment: @AtulOHolic Just to be sure. When you change background to static color, it works, but with selector nothing happens? Do you have different colors in selector? Do you really use correct selector?

Comment: i have done the same what ever mentioned on the above answer,but i am not able to get the color of the text changed.It remains same

Comment: sorry..i was using setcolor() instead of setcolorstatelist()...awesome solution man..

Answer (score 25):

1) First of all create color folder under res (/res/color)
2) create xml file selector.xml under /res/color folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:color="#504f4f" /> 
</selector>
```

3) Then in the populateTabStrip() method in SlidingTabLayout put this

```
tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
```

now you have a selector and you can change the color of the text on any event you want

if that is not working add the following lines of code.
a) in populateTabStrip() method at the end add this

```
if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
    tabView.setSelected(true);
}
```

and b) change the onPageSelected() method to this

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
        }
        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I am using already. I did exactly like your code. But it is not changing the colors.

Comment: i use the same code and is working i can send you my code from slidingtabs if you want

Comment: That will be really great if you can share. Is it on github? I can grab it from there.

Comment: @Abhi i have added the code here http://1drv.ms/1JjFSg7 change the files and read the .txt file

Comment: the first 3 steps should work. except be careful about which "R" you reference. it wasn't working well for me till I realized that one needed to use the project's package and not the android one like so: 
`tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(*<your package name>*.R.color.selector));`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem but I was using a custom page title View with an icon and a text. To set custom colors when a tab is selected/unselected, I used the selector created by @PanayiotisIrakleous, so a big thanks to him for posting it.

Here's how I did it:-

1- Create a xml file for the selector. I made a file, `slidingtab_title_color.xml` and placed it in `Drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:color="#504f4f" />
</selector>
```

2- Open your custom layout for tab title and add the `selector` file in the `android:textColor` attribute. My custom file is named as `slidingtab_title_color.xml` and has the following code-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<!--Adding the selector file in textColor attribute-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="@drawable/slidingtab_title_color"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

3- (Optional) If you want to change the color of the indicator and the background of sliding tab then add the following line to the file where you are initializing your `SlidingTabLayout`-

```
mSlidingTab.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
mSlidingTab.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor));
```

*Just make sure that you are adding these lines before you are setting the `ViewPager` for the `SlidingTabLayout`.*

And that's it, here's how it will look.[image: SlidingTab with tab selector]

For those who still have problems, here's the [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/rohankandwal/material-design/src/b54def77086c1d8039194aabef9b512367418bcd/11.%20SlidingTab%20with%20Icon%20and%20Text/) link for the project source and [this](https://bitbucket.org/rohankandwal/material-design/src) link for the all the projects on Material design.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested in another solution without using a Selector XML resource file, here is one somehow based on @Panayiotis' answer.

Add the below methods to the **SlidingTabStrip.java** class:

```
public void setTabTitlesTextColor(int selectedPosition) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (TextView.class.isInstance(getChildAt(i))) {
            ((TextView) getChildAt(i)).setTextColor((selectedPosition == i) ? getTabColorizer().getIndicatorColor(i) : Color.argb(90, 0,0,0)  );
        }
    }
}

public SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer getTabColorizer() {
    if (mCustomTabColorizer != null)
        return mCustomTabColorizer;
    else
        return mDefaultTabColorizer;
}
```

Call the newly created **setTabTitlesTextColor()** method in **onPageSelected** and **setViewPager** on the **SlidingTabLayout.java** class as below:

```
public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
        mTabStrip.setTabTitlesTextColor(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }
}

@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }

        mTabStrip.setTabTitlesTextColor(position);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is a minor bug i guess, because every-time the activity is loaded the initially selected item is displayed in blue which corrects itself once you swipe to other tabs. May be we will have to call the **setTabTitlesTextColor()** function from some other position also.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function

```
private void setTabTextSelected(TextView textView, boolean selected){
        if (selected){
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
        }
        else{
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimaryDark));
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);

        }

    }
```

and called it in two functions in SlidingTabLayout:

1. at the end of populateTabStrip:

> ```
> setTabTextSelected(tabTitleView, i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
> ```

2. at onPageSelected:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
>               TextView textView = (TextView) mTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
>               setTabTextSelected(textView, position == i);
>             }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code in your onCreate() method.

```
tabTitleView.setTabTextColors(
    getResources().getColor(R.color.active), 
    getResources().getColor(R.color.inactive));
```