# SlidingTabLayout change background colour of tab when pressed

Tags: java, android, android-tabs, android-tablayout, android-color

I have created tabs for my application using this tutorial: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

I have done this successfully and now trying to change the colour of the tab when pressed. It seems to have a built in default colour and I have googled quite alot but found no answers.

I have found how to change the background colour of the actual tab but I need to change the background when pressed. Please can someone help me with this?

Note: this changed the background colour of the tab in normal state by adding it to the constructor of SlidingTabLayout

```
this.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimaryDark));
```

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: did you get any solution for that? .. I am too looking for same implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26462476/1051804)

But it suggest to use [SmartTabLayout library](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) which is better.