# how to move tab text color like indicator?

Tags: android, tabs

I have a tab layout with a custom layout for the tabs I want the text to be white when the tab is selected and grey when its not, I've achieved this with a state selector and it works perfectly when I slide from tab to tab or when I click on one, however I want to dynamically change the tab on a button click from a fragment so I'm using this:

```
   MainActivity.viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

when I use this to change the tab my text on the tab doesnt change but the indicator does,

so I tried setting up a switch (see below) and calling it when I change tabs like this:

```
  MainActivity.viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
  MainActivity.tabTitleColor();
```

and this works the tab I've moved to has white text and the tab I've moved from's text is grey, but if I click another tab after using my switch I get two tabs with white text (strangely swiping doesn't have this issue and works perfectly), the indicator is always in the correct position so I wonder if any one knows if I can get its (the indicators) position, I'm still new to all this so maybe there's a simpler answer

many thanks

heres my switch.... just in CASE! hahaha

```
    public static void tabTitleColor(){
    int position2 = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    switch (position2){
        case 0:
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            System.out.println("tab "+ position2);
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            System.out.println("tab "+ position2);
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            System.out.println("tab "+ position2);
            break;
        case 3:
            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(false);
            System.out.println("tab "+ position2);
            break;
    }
}
```

adding my selector as requested it lives in a folder named color

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:color="#d1c9c9" />
 </selector>
```

Comment: Try this      
   tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#457815"), Color.parseColor("#986527"));
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#124595"));

Comment: im sorry to ask @Rakshit Nawani but did you read my question? my main issue right now is changing the color back after its changed when you click a tab, if i swipe through them the tabs change color just fine its more about getting the selected tab properly i think, hope you can help

Comment: Please show your color state list

Comment: I believe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362555/custom-selected-tab-text-color-in-slidingtablayout has something to do with it but I'm still no closer to an actual piece of code to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this in the end by scrapping my custom view, selector, and switch and using some custom styles and changing the way i was changing tabs so my styles.xml looks like this

```
<style name="CustomTabLayoutStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/selected_text</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CustomTabTexStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTabTexStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/unselected_text</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

added it to my tablayout like this

```
style="@style/CustomTabLayoutStyle"
```

and then changed the way i was moving tabs to this

```
                TabLayout tabLayout = MainActivity.tabLayout;
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
                tab.select();
```

and everything is now hunky dorey